# Google sheets API authentication from .jar

Tags: java, oauth, google-sheets-api, google-client

I'm putting together a simple application that basically just reads and writes from google sheets (and stores some of that stuff in a postgres database in between operations) using IntelliJ. It all works fine when run locally, except it often (and I can't seem to tell when it "needs" to do this) forces me to open the web browser and validate by logging in.

However, I have to run this (as a .jar) every 10 minutes, and my way of doing this is putting it on an EC2 instance in AWS and using crontab. This means I can't have it forcing me to open up my web browser to validate stuff every time. Is there a way to authenticate without going through this process? The current authentication code looks like this:

```
private static Credential authorize() throws IOException, URISyntaxException {
        // Load client secrets.
        InputStream in = SKUListReader.class.getResourceAsStream("/client_secret.json");
        GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

        // Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
        GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow =
                new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES).setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY).setAccessType("offline").build();
        Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");
        System.out.println("Credentials saved to " + dataStoreDir.getAbsolutePath());
        return credential;
    }
```

Comment: I haven't tested it but you can try using a service account an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user for your authentication . Check this [tutorial](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-spreadsheet) though it's for nodejs it will help you understand how to user service account to access Google Sheet API.